# How can i give a numeric order to each line based on unique ID

Tags: awk

I'm working on big data set and I need to give and print a numeric order for each unique ID ($1) and want to delete the lines above 335 numeric order for each unique ID.

The data looks like

```
101  24  
101  13  
101  15  
102  25  
102  21  
102  23  
103  20  
103  12  
103  18
```

The output looks like this

```
101  24 1  
101  13 2  
101  15 3  
102  25 1  
102  21 2    
102  23 3  
103  20 1  
103  12 2  
103  18 3
```

Comment: How big is the dataset?

Comment: @James The data contains more than 11 million lines and 24 fields.

Comment: @Alula Is the file sorted by the first field, such that all lines with the same value are at one place in the file?

Comment: @Lars yes its sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below one

Input

```
$ cat f
101 24
101 13
101 15
102 25
102 21
102 23
103 20
103 12
103 18
```

Output

```
$ awk '{print $0,++a[$1]}' f
101 24 1
101 13 2
101 15 3
102 25 1
102 21 2
102 23 3
103 20 1
103 12 2
103 18 3
```

If data is sorted ( column1 ) then use below one, faster

```
$ awk '$1!=p{n=0}{print $0,++n; p=$1}' f
101 24 1
101 13 2
101 15 3
102 25 1
102 21 2
102 23 3
103 20 1
103 12 2
103 18 3
```

***To remove id above 335***

```
$ awk '$1!=p{n=0; p=$1}++n<335{print $0,n}' f


$ awk '++a[$1]<335{print $0,a[$1]}' f
```

Comment: Can it removes lines above 335 numeric order for each unique ID?

Comment: Apparently my solution was exactly same as the latter one ++. Use the latter anyway, it consumes less memory.

Comment: @JamesBrown brother happens sometimes, may be few seconds before you I posted :)